# Is it possible to set a boolean variable of a class true, Before creating object of that class?

Tags: java

Hi I have a requirement where i need the value of is4cselected true on the fly.

```
public class A {
        boolean is4cselected=false;
        public A(){
            //
    //
        }
        public void set4c(){
            is4cselected=true;
        }

    }
    class B{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            A a=new A();
            a.set4c();

        }

    }
```

I don't see it happening as we have to create object of class A first.

Is there any alternate way to achieve that? I mean to say i need is4cselected to be false in some if case and to be true in some if-else condition in main(). Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just set it to true instead of false by default.

Comment: Use a constructor with a parameter for it

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does mean "on the fly" in this context?

Comment: Yes, but should there be many is4cselected, one for each A that you have, or should there be only 1? If there is only 1, then see the static section of my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use of the static keyword for variables of the class itself

If is4cselected is associated with **all of class A** rather than just a specific instance of class A then you can use a static member (in other words, if there is only 1 `is4cselected`, shared between all `A`);

```
public class A {
     static boolean is4cselected=false;
        ......
```

Then you can call it as A.is4cselected, use `private`, `public` etc as usual

Alternatively if it *is* associated with a specific instance then just pass it in the constructor

## Use of constructors to initialise an instance of a class

```
public class A {
    boolean is4cselected;
    public A(boolean is4cselected){
          this.is4cselected=is4cselected;
    }
    ......
```

You would create class A like so;

```
A a=new A(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a constructor that takes a boolean value for that field, and call that instead when you want to create an instance of the class with a value other than the default:

```
public A(boolean is4cselected){
    this.is4cselected = is4cselected
}
```

Then:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    A a = new A(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the value of an instance member (`is4cselected`) before you have an instance.

You *can* add a constructor that lets you set that value before anything outside `A` has access to the instance:

```
public A(boolean sel) {
    is4cselected = sel;
}
```

...which you would use in `B` like this:

```
A a = new A(true);
```

Or you can add a factory function for it:

```
public static A buildWithFlagSet() {
    A rv = new A();
    rv.set4c();
    return rv;
}
```

...which you would use in `B` like this:

```
A a = A.buildWithFlagSet();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A {
    boolean is4cselected=false;
    public A(is4cselected){
        this.is4cselected = is4cselected;
    }
    public void set4c(){
        is4cselected=true;
    }

}
class B{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A a=new A(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

YES:

look @ static {} I added to your code

```
public class A {
    static{
        boolean is4cselected=false;
    }

        public A(){
            //
    //
        }
        public void set4c(){
            is4cselected=true;
        }

    }
    class B{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            A a=new A();
            a.set4c();

        }

    }
```

Comment: That removes the member entirely, making it a local variable in the `static` block, and making the result not compile.

Comment: @RamonBoza In this case it will set false by default. My requirement is in the main method, in some if it needs to be false and in some else if it should be true. I don't see static doing this trick here...

Comment: A static block is a static method that runs when the class is loaded, if it effects nothing outside itself (as this one does) then it may as well not run at all